# Standards for username

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Prompted from seeing [this user](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/179337).

Is there a standard for what constitutes an "acceptable username"?

Also what would be the appropriate response to seeing a potentially offensive username? Raise a meta post, or custom flag on their question/answer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Flag any post made by the user (since you can't flag profiles directly) with a custom message to the mods explaining that the username may be problematic.

I've reset the username on this account this time.

Comment: That answers what to do when you see a username that violates the standard, but doesn't say what the standard *is*.

Comment: @DCShannon There aren't any afaict: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117596/212576

Comment: Huh. So, if a moderator sees something flagged as possibly offensive, how do you make that decision if you don't have a guideline? Just a subjective opinion of what's offensive based on your own judgement?

Comment: @DCShannon - Don't flag as 'offensive', flag with a custom reason to explain the bad username as Strix covered. We're not mind readers, we might miss the username and if we can't see anything wrong the post we will just decline.

Comment: @Robotnik Yes, that's what I meant, as described in the answer. I'm still curious how a moderator is supposed to decide whether something is "problematic" without a standard to use as a guideline. Seems like that would also be problematic.

Comment: @DCShannon - I think we can just use our good judgement. :-) Moderators exist to handle exceptional circumstances like this: that's why the SE team built the moderation toolset and also why the community votes for them - they're generally thought to be level-headed enough to handle it.

Comment: Usernames must abide by the [Be Nice policy](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), which while open to some interpretation, is often rather easy to determine if a violation exists - especially when reviewed by experienced community elected moderators. Specifically, this clause applies to this situation: "Inappropriate language or attention. Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive."

Comment: @TravisJ There we go. That works as a policy to refer to.

Answer (score 3):

Travis J wrote in a comment:

> Usernames must abide by the [Be Nice policy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), which while open to some interpretation, is often rather easy to determine if a violation exists - especially when reviewed by experienced community elected moderators. Specifically, this clause applies to this situation: "Inappropriate language or attention. Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive."